# Issue : Changing screen orientation in different activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-screen-support, android-screen

I have the main Activity which has 4 images on the canvas with the screen Orientation as "portrait". When I traverse to the child Activity which has the screen Orientation as "landscape".

Issue :  When I come back from the child Activity to the main Activity the 4 images are relocated to different position. I need to resolve this so that the Activity is fine even for the change in screen orientation.

Thanks in Advance.

Layout

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black">
   <activity
        android:name=".DragDrop"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"  
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"   >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 


    <activity
        android:name=".QuizHard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"   >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUIZHARD" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: When you came back, what is the orientation? post your layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the orientation to portrait of main activity and landscape of child activity in android manifest file.

```
       <activity android:name="Main"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

similarly set orientation to landscape for child activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can add statements to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to tell it to handle certain screen changes, such as orientation changes. Normally, when the orientation changes, a new layout is loaded and the screen is recreated, by adding this statement to the manifest file, it won't recreate the view. Change the activity declaration of your activities and add this statement.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The `android:configChanges="orientation"` will prevent Android from recreating the activity, thus preventing it from reloading the view and changing the image positions. You can also add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` right after the configChanges statement if you want Android to lock the orientation to portrait, or landscape, if you want.
Hope this helps! Would love to hear back from you with the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can add orientation to activity in manifest like this

```
<activity android:name="Main" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

or you can set layout orientation in java file like this

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```